# elementary calculus theorem proof

Tags: calculus, integration

> THEOREM :
>
> if a function f(x,y) is continuous in a closed region D , then there
>   is a limit of the sequence (II) of integral sums (I) if the maximum
>   diameter of the subregions $\Delta s_i$ approaches zero as $n \to
>  \infty $. this limit is the same for any sequence of type (II).
>
> $(I) \quad V_n=F(p_1)\Delta s_1+F(p_2) \, \Delta s_2+\cdots+F(p_n) \, \Delta s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n F(p_i) \, \Delta s_i$
>
> $(II) \quad V_{n_1},V_{n_2},\ldots,V_{n_k},\ldots$

I accepted it without proof when i studied calculus.
that is clear but not for me .why limit exist? and why limit is same for any sequence of type (II) ? i want to know what is the mathematical proof for this theorem or help me where should i start ??

Comment: You might want to check out this proof wiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Function_is_Riemann_Integrable

Comment: This is very helpful .Thanks @kccu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing $V_m=\sum_{j=1}^m F(q_j)\Delta \tilde{s}_j$, you have:
$$ V_n-V_m = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m (F(p_i)-F(q_j)) \left|\Delta s_i \cap \Delta \tilde{s}_j\right|$$
where $ \left| A \right|$ is the measure (area) of a set $A$.
The only non-zero contributions are when $\Delta s_i \cap \Delta \tilde{s}_j$ is non-empty but then $F(p_i)-F(q_j)$ is small (uniformly by compactness). So the sequence is Cauchy. But the argument does assume some definitions and additivity property of areas.

Comment: Thanks sir .can i ask you why you take$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(p_{i})(\Delta s_{i}) - \sum_{j=1}^{m}f(q_{j})(\Delta \bar s_{j}) = $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(p_{i})(\Delta s_{i}\cap \Delta \bar s_{j})- \sum_{j=1}^{m}f(q_{j})(\Delta s_{i}\cap \Delta \bar s_{j})$ or
 $\Delta s_{i}=\Delta s_{i}\cap \Delta \bar s_{j} $ or $\Delta s_{j}= \Delta s_{i}\cap \Delta \bar s_{j} $ ? i'm sorry because maybe it's be so elementary but i don't know .

Comment: In fact each collection $(\Delta s_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ and  $(\Delta \tilde{s}_j)_{1\leq j \leq m}$ forms a partition of your domain (assuming we may neglect the boundary) . So one has for, say fixed $i$: $\sum_j |\Delta s_i \cap \Delta \tilde{s}_j| = |\Delta s_i|$ which then yields the equality.